# Python list comprehension with two lists: evaluate lists

Tags: python, list, if-statement, list-comprehension

I have two lists:

```
input_list = ['a','b']
existing_list = ['q','w','r']
```

I want to create a new list that will be equal to `input_list` if it's not empty else it should be equal to `existing_list`.

The easiest way to do this is to use the plain `if-else`:

```
if input_list:
  list_to_use = input_list
else:
  list_to_use = existing_list
```

Is it possible to do this in a list comprehension or in any other manner that is more concise?

```
list_to_use = [x if input_list else y for y in existing_list for x in input_list]
```

The closest I could get is with this one that produces `['a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b']`, a wrong result.

Comment: Thanks for the accept but I wrote it just to be an alternative. Upvoted answer (that uses `or`) is the one you should use for sure.

Comment: @Lafexlos, I will. It just seems to be more intuitive for a reader imho.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Other than `or`, that suggested by Kasramvd (which should be *the* way to do this), you can also use [ternary operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/does-python-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator).

```
list_to_use = input_list if input_list else existing_list
```

Answer (score 5):

You don't need a list comprehension. That's exactly what `or` operation does:

```
>>> input_list or existing_list 
['a', 'b']
>>> input_list = []
>>> 
>>> input_list or existing_list 
['q', 'w', 'r']
```

Comment: "Keep It Simple & Stupid" .. :)